# Add a second class to the main class for an annual compensation calculator

Tags: java

I tried searching for this answer and found several answers that were similar to what I am looking for, but I can't seem to apply the suggestions provided on unrelated data to my specific program.

I need to take this working code I have created (a program to calculate an employee's annual compensation) and adjust it in a way that shows two classes (per the instructions of my homework assignment). The output given is exactly what I want, I just need help to reorganize the code so there is more than the main class. Is this something I can get help with here?

Here is my working code:

```
public class AnnualCompensation {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //create salary variable and commission percentage variable 
        double salary = 60000;

        double commissionPercentage = 0.06;

        //create command output for the user to get directions to enter value
        System.out.println("Enter total amount of sales for the year: ");
        double value = input.nextDouble();

        double totalCompensation = (value * commissionPercentage) + salary;
        System.out.println("Your annual compensation is: " + "$" + totalCompensation);    
    }  
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can put the logic inside a new method.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, can you be a little more specific about what the assignment states about the 2 classes?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help so far. I will copy and paste the instructions here:

Include:
The application should have at least one class, in addition to the application's controlling class (a controlling class is where the main function resides)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you can move the logic inside new class.

AnnualCompensationCalculator.java

```
 public class AnnualCompensationCalculator{
    private static double commissionPercentage = 0.06;
        public static double calculateCompensation(double sales ,double salary){
             return((sales * commissionPercentage) + salary);
        }
    }
```

AnnualCompensation .java

```
public class AnnualCompensation {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //create salary variable and commission percentage variable 
        double salary = 60000;

        //create command output for the user to get directions to enter value
        System.out.println("Enter total amount of sales for the year: ");
        double value = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Your annual compensation is: " + "$" + AnnualCompensationCalculator.calculateCompensation(value,salary));    
    }  
}
```

Comment: The assignment clearly asks for 2 classes. While this can be done, its not not an answer.

Comment: @zengr hope now the answer is ok.

Comment: Thank you for all the help, in order to create AnnualCompensationCalculator class, do I need to make it a .java file first?

Comment: @AshleyCM make it as a seperate .java file.

Comment: Thank you, @RajithPemabandu I have done this and it creates a file next to the original one in Netbeans. Do I link them in a certain way (like how I would have to call my css file in an html file in order to see the changes take effect?)

Comment: No need as they resides in the same package. in your case `default package` i suppose. you can accept the answer if its fine.

Comment: Thank you, @RajithPemabandu, that worked. Now another silly question- to send this code to my instructor do I send two separate files (AnnualCompensation.java and AnnualCompensationCalculator.java) or is there a way to send the whole packet as one file?

Comment: suppose you send the two files or the netbeans project

Comment: Thank you- I just had it in my head that the code all needed to be on one page and that is what was throwing me the entire time. Did I accept your answer properly? Never used this before..

Answer (score 1):

1. create a class `Employee` with `salary` and `commissionPercentage` as the fields.
2. In constructor  take the salary and commision% of employee and initate the fields.
3. in this class `Employee` create a method which will take `vavlue` as input and will calculate the compensation and return it.
4. So from main create the instance of `Employee` class and call the calculateMethod.

Answer (score 1):

I would structure it with these classes:

- `AnnualCompensationCalculator` which will do the computation for you as a utility class, and
- `AnnualCompensation` main class which would be focused on requesting for the user input (and would call the calculator).

Comment: yes this approach would be better as for the given instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Following Object Oriented Programming, I suggest you create a new class `Employee` that holds the salary and compensation percentage of an employee, which also has a method for calculating the compensation.

Like this:

```
class Employee {
    private double salary;
    private double commPercent;

    public Employee(double salary, double commPercent) {
        this.salary = salary;
        this.commPercent = commPercent;
    }

    public double calculateCompensation(double totalSales) {
        return (totalSales * commPercent) + salary;
    }

    /* Setters & Getters */
    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public double getCommPercent() {
        return commPercent;
    }

    public void setCommPercent(double commPercent) {
        this.commPercent = commPercent;
    }
}
```

Then have your main class use this `Employee` class to do all the work:

```
public class AnnualCompensation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Initialize an Employee object
        Employee emp = new Employee(60000, 0.06);

        //Create command output for the user to get directions to enter value
        System.out.print("Enter total amount of sales for the year: ");
        Scanner input   = new Scanner(System.in);
        double salesAmt = input.nextDouble();

        //Calculate the compensation based on the user input then print it              
        System.out.println("Your annual compensation is: $" 
                + emp.calculateCompensation(salesAmt));
    }
}
```